# User defined upstart jobs using Openbox

Tags: upstart, openbox

I know that to enable user defined jobs for upstart you need to uncomment `ubuntu` in `/etc/upstart-xsessions` and this will allow user defined upstart jobs in ubuntu default Xsession.

The question is how to enable user defined upstart jobs using different session (e.g. openbox) I thought that this should be as easy as adding `openbox` line to `/etc/upstart-xsessions`. But after adding this line openbox just hangs during startup and I end up with having no window manager at all.

Comment: Try this guide.https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with xmonad and found the following solution.

When you add `openbox` to `/etc/upstart-xsessions`, the script `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99upstart` substitutes the value of `STARTUP` environment variable with `init --user`, therefore openbox is not started by X.

To be able to run selected xsession, upstart emits event `xsession` with environment variable`SESSION` equal to your xsession. For xmonad I wrote the following script and put it to `~/.config/upstart/xmonad.conf`:

```
start on xsession SESSION=xmonad
stop on session-end

exec xmonad
```

I think you should just substitute all `xmonad` with `openbox`. If you want system-wide solution you have to put this script to `/etc/init/`